# Making triangular hat

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible in Latex to make a triangular hat? The one that is used in math over three letters representing points to indicate a triangle.

Something like: [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: something like this could work: `\(A \overset{\triangle}{B} C\)`

Comment: @RunarTrollet Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: First time I see this notation for triangles. Usually I use inline `$\triangle ABC$`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done using the `\overset` command, which takes two arguments. The first argument would be the symbol or character that you want to place on top, while the second would be the main character. `\overset{\triangle}{ABC}` would produce the result you are after, with a triangle centered above `ABC`

This requires `amsmath`-package. I tend to load `mathtools`, as it fixes some stuff from `amsmath`, and is generally advisable to use. You can find out more about the command, and related once in section 4.10 in the documentation for `amsmath`.

Not that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc amsmath`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

It might sound tedious to look up the documentation for various small problems/features, but the package documentations tend to be well-written and easy to browse. Also, it will at the same time help you to understand how LaTeX works.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

As you can see in triangle \(\overset{\triangle}{ABC}\), alternatively \(\triangle ABC\) would probably be better for inline, as it doesn't require so much text-height.
\end{document}
```