# How to denote an angle and a triangle in a formula in Latex?

Tags: angle

I'm almost new to Latex, and I need to denote an angle D, and a triangle ABC as the following in Latex. Ho can I do that?

[image]

[image]

I know that there are other more standard ways to denote angles and triangles in math docs, but I just need the above format.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401309/triangle-notation-in-spain)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! - Other related link : [Making triangular hat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317518/124842)

Comment: Thank you very much  @bobyandbob. Found what I was looking for at the link you mentioned.

Comment: Also, for angle symbol "caret", you can use `\widehat{ABC}`. See [How to typeset the symbol “^” (caret/circumflex/hat)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typeset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex-hat)